# How to display placeholder in safari

Tags: java, jquery, html, safari

I have used one `textarea` where i have used one attribute `placeholder` but i found that the placeholder is working in all other browser but safari.

```
<textarea class="concerncommentArea" placeholder="Place you comment here"/>"> </textarea>
```

Can somebody help me how to display placeholder in safari? 
I am using safari v5.1.7

In Inspect element console the output is coming like this.
[image]

Comment: Please try my answer. It's work fine with safari 5.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a space between start and end tag `<textarea> </textarea>` and you syntax is false. Please try:

```
<textarea class="concerncommentArea" placeholder="Place you comment here"></textarea>
```

Comment: Frank, I have tried it like `<textarea class="concerncommentArea" placeholder="Place you comment here"></textarea>` but sadly no success.

Comment: Why you have double closure? put just `<textarea class="concerncommentArea" placeholder="Place you comment here"></textarea>` and not `<textarea class="concerncommentArea" placeholder="Place you comment here"/>"></textarea>`

Comment: Oh that is my mistake here i have edited the comment any by mistake added that html tag "/>"

Comment: If in your code you are write `placeholder="Place you comment here"/>">` this is wrong. Remove `/>"` from placeholder. now the right code is `placeholder="Place you comment here">`

Comment: or please paste you right code in your question :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153743/discussion-between-p-frank-and-akash).

Answer (score 0):

placeholders work in Safari 5+. Check out MDN
[Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Browser_Compatibility)

Comment: Safari 1.5.7 doesn't exist. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)#Safari_1) He wanted to say 5.1.7 :-)